# CSS Transition doesn't work with width

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-transitions

When I was creating my dropdown menu I discovered a problem, I've been googling for one hour and now I want to ask. So I want to increase the width and the background at the same time with the transition, but it just changes the opacity just take a look at the code snippet and hover over the submenu and you will see it just changes the opacity. The thing is I want it to increase the width with transition.

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #333;
}
.nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #333;
}
.nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Sansa_Light;
  width: 170px;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  /*width:170px;*/
}
.nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  width: 170px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
.nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inherit;
}
.nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Test drop</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Dropped</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Non drop</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want a smooth transition to be not only on hover (but on unhover too), you should add a `transition` property for main selected, not only on `:hover` selector.
2. You forgot to add a `transition` property for `<ul>`, now it's only on `<a>`.
3. [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/display) property is not [*animatable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties), you should use [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) + [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).
4. Old vendor prefixes for `transition` (like `-o` and `-moz`) aren't actual now, see [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20transition).

```css
.nav {
    background-color: #333;
}

.nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 170px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.nav ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    top: 60px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.nav ul ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display: list-item;
}

.nav ul ul ul li {
    top: -60px;
    left: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Test drop</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Dropped</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Non drop</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `display` isn't an *Animatable* CSS property, so you can't using *transition* properties on it!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp

> as @sergey-denisov said, `display` property is not animatable, you should use `opacity + visibility`!

#### a live demo: https://codepen.io/gildata/pen/bopoQZ

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hans">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .showPanel {
            /* display: block; */
            visibility: visible;
            /* opacity === 不透明度 1 & 不透明 === opaque */
            opacity: 1;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            /* transform: translateX(100px); */
            -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in 0.5s;
            transition: all 1.0s ease-in 0.5s;
        }
        
        .hidePanel {
            /* display: none; */
            visibility: hidden;
            /* opacity === 不透明度 0 & 透明 === transparent */
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            /* transform: translateX(-100px); */
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0.5s;
            transition: all 1s ease 0.5s;
            /* 
            -webkit-transition: property duration timing-function delay;
            -moz-transition: property duration timing-function delay;
            transition: property duration timing-function delay; */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <!-- js in HTML ??? onclick="test(e);" -->
        <button id="btn">button</button>
        <div class="showPanel" id="panel">
            <div>
                content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br> content <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <pre>
                .showPanel {
                    display: block;
                    /* height: 100%; */
                    /* transform: translateX(100px); */
                    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-in 0.5s;
                    transition: all 1.0s ease-in 0.5s;
                }
                
                .hidePanel {
                    display: none;
                    /* height: 0; */
                    /* transform: translateX(-100px); */
                    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-out 0.5s;
                    transition: all 1.0s ease-out 0.5s;
                    /* 
                    -webkit-transition: property duration timing-function delay;
                    -moz-transition: property duration timing-function delay;
                    transition: property duration timing-function delay;
                    */
                }
        </pre>
    </div>
    <script>
        const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
        const panel = document.querySelector("#panel");
        btn.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
            console.log(`e = \n`, e);
            let className = panel.className;
            if (className === "showPanel") {
                panel.className = "hidePanel";
            } else {
                panel.className = "showPanel";
            }
        });
        const test = (e) => {
            console.log(`e = \n`, e);
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```